# How to get the next $args when if:false?

Tags: php, if-statement

I am new in programming... (The question absolutely about programming, but I use wordpress) I try to be very clear:

I have a subdomain based multisite network. If the users posts to their sites, I get a clone from the current post to my network home. This clone have a canonical url, what shows to the original post, and the post slug's also concur (the ID's dont.)

example: x user posted:

```
   url: xusersite.network.com/4243345/this-is-slug-by-post-title
   canonical: xusersite.network.com/4243345/this-is-slug-by-post-title
```

I get:

```
   url: network.com/123677745/this-is-slug-by-post-title
   canonical: xusersite.network.com/4243345/this-is-slug-by-post-title
```

Now I want get the clone post's ID, on the subsite, by the original post... so I have this code:

```
   switch_to_blog( 1 );
   $canonical = 'xusersite.network.com/4243345/this-is-slug-by-post-title';
   $slug = 'this-is-slug-by-post-title'; // current slug
   $args = array(
     'name'        => $slug,
     'post_type'   => 'post',
     'post_status' => 'publish',
     'numberposts' => 1
   );
   $my_posts = get_posts($args);
```

Thats ok, but the problem, if an another user posted with the same title for his blog, example: y user posted:

```
   url: yusersite.network.com/72543/this-is-slug-by-post-title
   canonical: yusersite.network.com/72543/this-is-slug-by-post-title
```

I get a post, with the same slug:

```
   url: network.com/776536556733/this-is-slug-by-post-title
   canonical: yusersite.network.com/72543/this-is-slug-by-post-title
```

So my php knowledge now here it is, I can do this:

```
   if( $my_posts ) :
     $cloneid = $my_posts[0]->ID;
     $clonecanonical = wp_get_canonical_url( $cloneid );
     if( $clonecanonical == $canonical ) :
     $exit = 'true';
     else : 
     $exit = 'false';
     endif;
   endif;
```

How can I get the next $my_posts, so $my_posts[1]->ID, if the $exit is false? How can I get the right $my_posts?

Comment: Setting boolean's as strings =(. Excuse my ignorance about the wordpress systems, but could you tell us how `776536556733` comes about?

Comment: Is it possible within wordpress to not focus on the `slug` but instead opt for using that id within the url?

Comment: the ID is the post's ID, and on my network I add it the current second to the permalink structure, so example the thousandth get an ID = 1000 and this was published 13:22:42 then the permalink: network/100042/slug ...

Comment: I know only the slug, from the original post, because that the same like on the clone... The IDs (ID+SEC) changes, so I cannot get this value from the original post's url...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to have understood, but you should get the numeer of posts in my posts using count($my_posts) and then use a for or while to iterate through the full $my_posts.

something like this:

```
    if( $my_posts ) :
    $numPosts=count($my_posts)
    //if $numPosts = 0 then $my_posts[0] does not exist
    //but if you are here $numPosts must be > 0
    if $numPosts > 0 {
        for ( $i = 0; $i < $numPosts; $i++ ){
            $cloneid = $my_posts[$i]->ID;
            $clonecanonical = wp_get_canonical_url( $cloneid );
            if( $clonecanonical == $canonical ) :
        $exit = $my_posts[$i]->ID;
    endif;
        }
    }
    endif;
```

Comment: I modify your code, what do you think? I will test now

Comment: Any error?

If you have at least one post, you ought to get values.

Comment: I work now with this, the problem firstly was in my code, when I use 'name' => $slug, this find one post (the $my_posts[0]), but not more... Now I use 'post_name' => $slug, this find the all posts, but the for not working (and I edit your code, change the 0 to 1 because 1 post exists in every case)

Comment: @GalgócziLevente Your edit was declined. You changed it from "if there are more than 0" to "if there are more than 1" which in your case means there would have to be at least 2 for it to be true

Comment: To change the starting counter from 0 to 1 is not correct, you would skip the first post. Delete instead the if (if $numPosts > 0), as it is useless in this case.

You should also try to var_dump($my_posts) to understand how many posts you are getting by get_posts($args).